# Good way to get count of children?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have two tables with parent - child relationship:

**PARENT** table with `id` as index

```
    id  | name
----------------
    1   | Bob
    2   | Mike
    3   | Joe
```

**CHILDREN** table with `id` as index

```
   id   | parent | name
-------------------------
    1   | 1      | Ronald
    2   | 2      | Sammy
    3   | 3      | Jenny
    4   | 1      | Tara
    5   | 3      | Jack
```

On my website I want to display list of **all** parents with count of their children as follows:

```
    id  | name | Children Count
-------------------------------
    1   | Bob  |      2
    2   | Mike |      1
    3   | Joe  |      2
```

What is the efficient way to do this? Note that here I represented an analogous simplified version of my data structure, in my actual situation I have about 10000 records in my `PARENT` table and each `parent` has about `10 - 200` `children`.

In case you suggest to add a `count` column to `PARENT` table, do you know of any way such that the `count` will be automatically updated by `MYSQL` when I make a change in the `CHILDREN` table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.name,
       COUNT(c.id) AS children_count
FROM parent p
LEFT JOIN children c ON p.id = c.parent
GROUP BY p.id
```

Comment: Can you justify why this is better than adding another column? Will performance be an issue?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this could work

```
select p.id, p.name, c.cnt
from parent p
inner join (select parent, count(id) cnt 
            from children
            group by parent) c on p.id = c.parent
```

Comment: Can you justify why this is better than adding another column? Will performance be an issue?

Comment: I didn't say it's better. Adding another column helps queries, but complicates writes.

Comment: Add index on parent in children table and performance won't be an issue, at least not until you have millions of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, COUNT(b.name) 
FROM parent a 
INNER JOIN children b  
ON a.id = b.parent 
GROUP BY b.parent;
```